# Is it possible to have multiple full page background images in different components of an React App?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am creating a simple app with login, sign up and a home page. I want different full screen background image on each component. I set up 3 different CSS files for each component but all 3 components are taking the same background image. How can I achieve different background images?

Here is the CSS that I am using to set a full background image.

```
html  {
    min-height:100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541) 50%), url("login.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size:cover; }
```

I expect to have each component their own background image.

Comment: This is because you are setting image to `html` try using your app container instead where you are loading your app.

Comment: The code you are posting is not enough for a proper answer... What you can do is add a class corresponding to each background image in your body tag and update it depending of the page you are showing. Without more code from you I cannot be more specific.

Comment: @DarpanRangari I am very much new to react. Can you please tell how to set the background to an app container in the externall css?

Comment: @StavrosAngelis If I do that the image doesn't come full page perfectly. It takes up the size of the div element only.

Comment: Are you sure you add the class to your body tag? If so then add a css class : body { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0 } to make sure that your body covers the full window.

Comment: @StavrosAngelis this almost worked, but I have a tiny bit of borders all around.

Comment: also set margin:0; border: 0 none;

Comment: I just noticed the problem. When I import a CSS file in one component it is being applied to all the other components. It is overriding the CSS that I had imported. I guess if I am able to circumvent this, I will fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your problem, it seems you are not setting the background image for a specific component. Assuming this is client-side rendered single page app, HTML is not getting reconciled, only your components are getting updated.
Try to set up a background image within the component.

Comment: I have set up 3 css files and import them in each component. Like in signup.js I importsignup.css which has the same code as in the question but with an different image. Yet it is not working.

Comment: Is there any codepen or gist available to look at it?

Comment: create three different classes and pass them as a property of your component and apply on your html tag.

Comment: I just noticed the problem. When I import a CSS file in one component it is being applied to all the other components. It is overriding the CSS that I had imported. I guess if I am able to circumvent this, I will fix my problem.